# Where is the common-sense button that aligns curve handles and resets them?

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves

All I want to do is make a simple spline IK. Apparently this is impossible because in order to construct one, I very expectedly have to move the curve handles. Moving the curve vertices automatically misaligns the handles so that they don't point towards each other to keep a straight line, even though they should.

I tried all kinds of selection to cursor and snapping techniques, none of which work because the lengths of the handles are no longer at their default value. How can I get blender to do what it is supposed to and construct a simple, straight segment of merely two handles pointed towards each other at their default length?

Answer (score 3):

Edit Mode:

- <kbd>A</kbd> Select all
- <kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> Convert control points to Vector

With just 2 points, this will produce the straight line I think you're looking for? I do this to every Bezier curve on creation..  it just helps get off to a known, 'neutral' start.

After that, you might want to <kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> subdivide, (or, in 2.8 right click > Subdivide) to make more in-line vertices.

Comment: That didn't work. Luckily I coincidentally found a button "recalculate normals" that did it.

Comment: I must be missing a difference between your situation and mine?.. tried in both 279 and 28.. works for me.. recalc straightens, but doesn't equalize handles